# Is there a Firebase storage rules syntax highlighter for WebStorm?

Tags: firebase, webstorm, syntax-highlighting

I opened the Firebase [friendlychat-web](https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat-web) (GitHub) sample project (`web` folder) in WebStorm.

Unfortunately, the `storage.rules` file opens without syntax highlighting. There's no WebStore plugin for Firebase development. The language used for the storage rules is a custom one.

Has anyone crafted / is aware of a syntax highlighter I could use?

[image]

Comment: You can vote for the feature in JetBrains backlog here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-7927?p=IDEA-200507

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best you can do ATM is to add some colors by creating a new file type under `Settings->Editor->File Types`.

You can get it to look like this:
[image]

This is how first page of my config looks like: [image]

The only downside is that highlighter is only aware of certain words but not of the syntax, so it would highlight word no matter where you use it.

Answer (score 1):

Now is possible to highlight syntax for firebase rules, there is a plugin available in this link: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/15189-firebase-rules-syntax-highlighter

with that plugin you could be able to highlight and check syntax.

Comment: Works for highlighting syntax, but not for checking, I would say.  My fast try: add "+++" in the middle of the rules. No highlight to show it as a failure.

Comment: that issue will be fixed for version 2.0.0, thanks for testing the plugin.